# How to copy the value from Userform textbox to multple cells in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a simple Userform with two textboxes.  User is to enter Part Description in one labelled "Panel ID" and the number of rows that description is to be entered in the same column of the spreadsheet (Quantity). By now, I am OK with adding value in empty row, but got stuck at copying the value to other cells.  I have code for copying the value in set range, but cannot find anything that works for what I am looking for.  Thanks

[Apples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnRsL.png) [Oranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG12W.png) [List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFg4h.png)

```
  Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click()
  Dim iRow As Long, C As Long
  Dim sh As Worksheet


  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

  iRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  C = QTYBox.Value

  With sh

  .Cells(iRow, 1) = TxtPanel.Value
  
  End With

  End Sub

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  'Empty Panel ID cell
  TxtPanel.Value = ""

  'Empty Quantity cell
  QTYBox.Value = ""

  'Set focus to panel ID cell
  TxtPanel.SetFocus

  End Sub
```

This is code for second problem:
[crate form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hycjp.png)
[crate spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWYgQ.png)

```vb
Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    lRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With sh
        For i = 2 To lRow

            'Criteria search        
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = PanelTxt.Value Then
                If .Cells(i, 2).Value = IDTxt.Value Then           
                    'Enter date in Crated and Crate #
                    .Cells(i, 5) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YY HH:MM")]
                    .Cells(i, 6) = CrateTxt.Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(C) = TxtPanel.Value`

Comment: Perfect.  As always, thanks a million...

Comment: Now I am on second part of the same table.  Different department is supposed to crate panels and scan which ones are crated.  When they submit ; I need Date and Crate # to be entered in columns E and F for correct Panel row (Panel ID and ID# "QTY").  I tried the code but it is doing nothing.    Not sure what is missing. Code is added to original message.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Maybe add Trim to `If .Cells(i, 1).Value = Trim(PanelTxt.Value) Then` in case it's just hidden spaces. I noticed you had `TxtPanel` in the first form and `PanelTxt` in the crating form, try to be consistent because that where the bugs love to hide :).

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing is happening.  Hmm, will try to play with it some more.  I changed set up with spreadsheets, so now it is completely separate spreadsheet with different form.  Just to see if some of bugs are hiding in having two different forms in the same spreadsheet.  But, it still doesn't work.